# How do I scale up a tensor's size by a given integer scale factor in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensor, tensorflow.js

I'm aware that one could implement a scaling function in vanilla JS, but if I  were to have a tensor such as this:

```js
a = tf.tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
a.print();
/*
Tensor
    [[1, 2],
     [3, 4]]
*/
```

Does Tensorflow.js have a native way of scaling a tensor up without converting it into a vanilla JS data structure first? For example, if I scaled the above tensor up by 2 in all dimensions, I'd get this:

```
Tensor
    [[1, 1, 2, 2],
     [1, 1, 2, 2],
     [3, 3, 4, 4],
     [3, 3, 4, 4]]
```

How can I scale a Tensorflow.js tensor up without first converting it into a vanilla JS data structure?

Answer (score 2):

`mirrorPad` will do just that

```
x = tf.tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])
x.mirrorPad([[1, 1], [1, 1]], 'symmetric').print();
```

Comment: Oh, nice! How does one specify, say, a scale factor or 3 or 5 for example? To you just adjust the number `1` to be `2` or something?

Comment: yeah, you will either have to play with the padding or add another mirrorPad such as the following for instance: `x.mirrorPad([[1, 1], [1, 1]], 'symmetric').mirrorPad([[1, 1], [0, 0]], 'symmetric')`